# Yii2 - multiple models - empty values becoming zeros in the form after unsuccessful validation

Tags: validation, yii2, active-form

I have a form where I'm collecting input for multiple models. When I'm submitting the form, and the validation is unsuccessful, the form fields that were empty before, are afterwards filled with zeros. Can you please tell me where it is happening and why, and how can I avoid it? Thank you very much!

Controller:

```
public function actionCreate($zg_id) {
    $zgmws = [new Zgmw()];
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        $zgmws[] = new Zgmw();
    }

    try {
        if (Model::loadMultiple($zgmws, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($zgmws)) {
            foreach ($zgmws as $zgmw) {
                if ($zgmw->value) {
                    $zgmw->save(false);
                }
            }
            return $this->redirect(Url::previous());
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        ...
    }
    return $this->render('create', [
        'zgmws' => $zgmws
    ]);
```

Form:

```
foreach ($zgmws as $index => $zgmw) {
    echo $form->field($zgmw, "[$index]value")->textInput([]);
}
```

Rules:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['value'], 'number', 'enableClientValidation' => false],
    ];
}
```

Comment: You're getting zeros after saving record to database or zeros in form after unsuccessful validation?

Comment: after unsuccessful validation

Comment: It seems to me that `Model::validateMultiple` is doing it. However there is absolutely no rule in `rules()` that a default value should be assigned when `empty`... how can it be? What can I do against this? Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: Are those fields with zeros valid properties? 
Please try to check the models' content after `Model::loadMultiple`, before validating. Is the mass assignment successful, and all the given fields are loaded?